# Generic class method computation based on variable input

Tags: c++, design-patterns, generic-programming

I roughly got the following setup:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Element{
    T getX() const;
    T getY() const;
 private:
    T x,y;
    std::vector<float> handling_times;
    float cost;
};

template<typename T, typename Tnext>
class Bloc {
     T getX() const;
     T getY() const;
 private:
     T x,y;
     Tnext num_blocs;
     float effort;
     float damage_done;
};

template<typename T>
class Measurements {
void calcMeasurements(const std::vector<T*> &data);
     float getMean() const;
 private:
     float mean;
};


int main() {
     std::vector<Element<int>*> elements;
     // fill with elements
     std::vector<Bloc<float,2>*> blocs;
     // fill with blocs

     // calculate mean of blocs effort
     Measurements<Bloc<float,1>> bloc_mean_effort_measurement;
     bloc_mean_effort_measurement.calcMeasurements(blocs);

     return 0;
 }
```

So two classes `Element` and `Bloc` which hold some data I'd like to perform `Measurements` on. For example, I'd like to measure the `getMean()` of an `Element`'s `handling_times` which is of type `std::vector<float>`. Another case would be to measure the mean of `std::vector<Bloc<float>*> blocs` based on the effort stored in each `Bloc`. As you can see the input types for an `Measurement` vary but the functionality behind the mean calculation always stays the same. I'd like to have this functionality only implemented once (mean is only the simplest example I could think of) and use it on different types. Furthermore, I can't get my head around, how to pass the `Measurement` object based on which entity (e.g. `Element` `costs` or `Bloc` `effort`) the measure should be computed. Would it make sense to have an `enum PossibleMeasurements` in `Element` with `HANDLING_TIMES` and `COSTS`. So to say for each private variable I would like to be able to compute measures on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correclty, you have more or less this:

```
struct A {
        std::vector<int> a;
};

struct B {
        int value;
        B(int x) : value(x) {}
};    
typedef std::vector<B> Bvect;
```

And now you want to calculate the mean of the values with the same generic function whether they are in an `A` or in a `Bvect`. This generic function already exists and is called `std::accumulate`. For the object containing the vector you would do

```
A foo;
foo.a.push_back(123);
std::cout << std::accumulate(foo.a.begin(),foo.a.end(),0.0) << "\n";
```

You have to pass two iterators indicating the first and one past the last element to be accumulated, and an initial value.

For the `Bvect` it looks quite similar, we just have to supply a custom way of adding up the elements:

```
Bvect b;
b.push_back(B(123));
std::cout << std::accumulate(b.begin(),
                             b.end(),
                             B(0),
                             [](B b1,B b2){
                                return B(b1.value + b2.value);
                             }).value << "\n";
```

I use a lambda to access the values to be added and construct a `B` holding the sum of the two values.

PS: This examples only calculate the sum, to get the average simply divide by number of elements.